# Allow only date format in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to enter the only date in selected columns. But I but want to apply in two more columns in (U and X). Can anyone help please how i can include other columns

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B20000")
    For Each c In r

        If c.Value <> "" And Not IsDate(c) Then
            c.ClearContents
            MsgBox "Please enter only date in this format DD/MM/YYYY "
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate solution creating a Sub and calling that sub from your `Worksheet_Change` event. You can call the Sub several times indicating the columns you need to validate.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call ValidateDate(2) 'For Column B
    Call ValidateDate(8) 'For Column H

End Sub


Private Sub ValidateDate(Col As Integer)

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, Col), Cells(20000, Col))
    For Each c In r
        If c.Value <> "" And Not IsDate(c) Then
            c.ClearContents
            MsgBox "Please enter only date in this format DD/MM/YYYY "
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: without `Application.EnableEvents` this will probably crash excel and is it will fire ontop of itself again and again each time `c.ClearContents` is called.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need of VBA for this. You can use [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) on the required cells.

However, if you absolutely want VBA, this is one way you can include other columns and also ensure the code only cares if one of the cells you care about was changed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim TestRange As Range

    Set TestRange = Me.Range("B2:B20000")
    Set TestRange = Union(TestRange, Me.Range("U2:U20000"))
    Set TestRange = Union(TestRange, Me.Range("U2:X20000"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, TestRange) Then

        Dim CheckCell As Range

        For Each CheckCell In TestRange

            If CheckCell.Value <> "" And Not IsDate(CheckCell) Then

                Application.EnableEvents = False
                CheckCell.ClearContents
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                MsgBox "Please enter only date in this format DD/MM/YYYY "

            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```